# jqGrid just show 10 rows

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, filtering

I'm very confuse for this problem due I'm new in jqGrid.
my data just show 10 rows. this my script;

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'dounfinish.php?q=1',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    closeafteredit:true,
    colNames:['id','Date', 'Line','Model','Lotno','Qty','PIC'],
    colModel :[ 
            {name:'id', index:'id', hidden:true, width:55}, 
            {name:'Date', index:'Date', width:90, editable:true, search:true, stype:'text',searchoption:{sopt:['cn']}}, 
            {name:'Line', index:'Line', width:80, editable:true, search:true, stype:'text',searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']}},
            {name:'Model', index:'Model', width:180, editable:true, search:true, stype:'text',searchoption:{sopt:['cn']}},
            {name:'Lotno', index:'Lotno', width:80, editable:true, search:true, stype:'text',searchoption:{sopt:['cn']}}, 
            {name:'Qty', index:'Qty', width:80, editable:true, search:true, stype:'text',searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']}},
            {name:'PIC', index:'PIC', width:180, editable:true, search:true, stype:'text',searchoption:{sopt:['cn']}}
            ],
//      pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    gridview:true,
    pager: '#pager',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'Date',
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
//      imgpath: 'themes/basic/images',
    caption: 'DAILY CHECK QTY',
    editurl:'process3.php',
    prmNames:{oper:'action',editoper:'editbaldefect',id:'def_id'}
});
```

the case like:

```
loadonce: true result View 1 - 10 of 10 --> column filter can work.
loadonce: false result View 1 - 10 of 3500 --> column filter not working.
```

Why??

---

at developer tools show:

```
{"page":1,"total":33223,"records":"332222","rows":[]}
```

but at php page appears:
[image]

---

UPDATE

my jqgrid using `datetype : json` and also need `loadonce : true`.I already trial like this:

1. change loadonce : false --> result all records show but can't use toolbar filter
2. change loadonce : true --> result only show 10 records but toolbar filter can work
3. loadonce : true, rowNum: 50 --> data show only 50 (next button disable)
4. check query at phpmyadmin --> result all data can show (query OK)
5. using another table (OK one) --> result still not work
6. Using another page then attach jqgrid --> still not work

why jqgrid just retrieve 10 records only however this table actually have 100.000 records?
and why just this table whereas another table can work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jqGrid was designed originally to be able to fill grid with server based data. The option `loadonce: true` was introduced later. So if you don't use `loadonce` (or if you use `loadonce: false`) **the server is responsible for paging, sorting and filtering of the data**. Every time if the user click on the column header to sort the data by the column or if the user fill searching toolbar the new request to the server will be sent. If the user change the number of rows per page (choose other value as 10 in the pager) the new request to the server will be also send. The options `page`, `rows`, `sidx`, `sord`, `_search` and typically `filters`. Default names of parameters which will be sent to the server can be chaneged by `prmNames` option of jqGrid (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)).

I personally use always `stringResult: true` option of `filterToolbar`. The format of `filters` parameter in the case is the same as for Advanced Searching (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching#options)).

If you use `loadonce: true` then jqGrid get the data from the server only **once**. So the server should return **all data** in the response independent on the `rows` parameter of jqGrid. The server should only sort the data correctly. The properties `page`, `total` and `records` from the server response will be *ignored*. The corresponding values will be recalculated based on the data from `rows`.

If you use `loadonce: true` then jqGrid change `datatype` to `"local"` after the first loading of data. So all later requests for sorting, paging and filtering of data will be implemented *locally* without any additional request to the server.

So if you use `loadonce: true` and the server return 10 rows of data then jqGrid display `"View 1 - 10 of 10"` because it found only 10 rows in the server response.

Comment: this page was copy from another page. For the original page it can works (the server page query using `SELECT *`), but for the this page not work (the server page query using `SELECT ...JOIN...`).

Comment: why the server response only 10 rows? actually my query get 100.000 more records.

Comment: @nunu: Sorry, but I answered already on the question before. If you don't use `loadonce: true` (or if you use `loadonce: false`) **your server is responsible for paging, sorting and filtering of the data**. jqGrid just send parameters `page`, `rows`, `sidx` etc. The server should returns the **requested page of sorted and filtered** data. The `"rows":[...]` part of the response contains the page of data, but `"page"`, `"total"` and `"records"` should be filled correctly. You fill definitively wrong information in the server response.

Comment: its really very strange for me, why page A could work but B page not. I don't know where the root cause for this problem cause. I try to copy jqgrid server script from page A to B and just change the query, after that I'm shocking my problem solved. it can work normally however nothing different between server script between A and B.